# Can we import huge amount of data through insert statements in sql queries in magento2?

Tags: database, dataflow, data-migration, insertlisting

We need to import huge data to magento database. Can anyone suggest me how can we achieve this through sql queries?or is there any standard approach other than code changes?

Comment: It's not possible by .sql file to import using cli?

Comment: why you don't use csv to import products?